# Rare error while computing dataframe by using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am dealing a rare error while making some machine learning with a dataset loaded using pandas.
This is the error I am getting: 
[image]

I have been reading something releated to it and it seems to be due to the columns and how pandas interpret them but I have no clue what can be wrong.
This is the code I am using for this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-
indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data'
col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 
'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
pima = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=col_names)
# define X and y
feature_cols = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 
'pedigree', 'age']
X = pima[feature_cols]
y = pima.label
#k fold cv
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
kf = KFold(n_splits=10) #define number of splits
kf.get_n_splits(X) #to check how many splits will be done.
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis() #select the model for train, test in kf.split(X, y):
for train, test in kf.split(X, y):
    y_pred_prob = clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    y_pred_class = clf.predict(X[test])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `clf.fit` method, according to the document parameters expected are `array`:

```
Parameters
----------
X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
    Training data.

y : array, shape (n_samples,)
```

If you look at the example in [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) `X` and `y` are `numpy array`:
Try using `as_matrix()` for both `X` and `y` instead of just `X = pima[feature_cols]` and `y = pima.label`

```
X = pima[feature_cols].as_matrix()
y = pima.label.as_matrix()
```

Testing by `print`:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data'
col_names = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age', 'label']
pima = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=col_names)

# define X and y
feature_cols = ['pregnant', 'glucose', 'bp', 'skin', 'insulin', 'bmi', 'pedigree', 'age']
X = pima[feature_cols].as_matrix()
y = pima.label.as_matrix()

#k fold cv
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
kf = KFold(n_splits=10) #define number of splits
kf.get_n_splits(X) #to check how many splits will be done.
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis() #select the model for train, test in kf.split(X, y):

for train, test in kf.split(X, y):
    y_pred_prob = clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    y_pred_class = clf.predict(X[test])
    print(y_pred_class)
```

Result:

```
[1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
 1 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
 0 1 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 1]
[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0]
```